# How do I create a List<T> from an instance of a class from a manually referenced DLL?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, class, reflection

I have an ASP.NET MVC Application.

I have an example class called Example

```
public class Example
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Property1{ get; set; }
    public string Property2{ get; set; }
}
```

I also have a test method - TestingCallFromSeparateConsoleApp that does some functionality and returns a List of Examples

```
public List<Example> TestingCallFromSeparateConsoleApp()
{
    List<Example> exampleList = new List<Example>();

    exampleList.Add(new Example
    {
        Id = 1,
        Property1 = "First",
        Property2 = "First",
    });

    exampleList.Add(new Example
    {
        Id = 2,
        Property1 = "Second",
        Property2 = "Second",
    });

    return exampleList;
}
```

I have a separate console application that is loading the MVC DLL manually.

I can call the TestingCallFromSeparateConsoleApp method and it returns the the result as type object.

I am trying to cast the result to its correct type of List of Examples.

```
 asm = Assembly.LoadFrom(assemblyFile);
 var smsAppInstance = asm.CreateInstance("EngineeringAssistantMVC.Controllers.TestController", false, BindingFlags.CreateInstance, null, null, null, null);

 var ExampleClass = asm.GetType("EngineeringAssistant.Controllers.Example", true);
 var ec = ExampleClass.GetType();
```

This gets the Example class details but I still cannot figure out how to actually instantiate and use a class of type "Example"

In my console How do I basically say:

```
ExampleClass newExampleClass = new ExampleClass();
```

So I can then say:

```
var result = smsAppInstance.GetType().GetMethod("TestingCallFromSeparateConsoleApp").Invoke(smsAppInstance, argumentsTopass);
```

Where result can be cast to `List<ExampleClass>`

EDIT 1

I am manually loading the dll file, I do not want to add it through the references.

Comment: Just reference the Dll in your console project and be done with it, wallah.. all typed

Comment: Indeed. If you know the name of the type there's no reason to use reflection to load it. Just instantiate it. Are you trying to create a plugin architecture perhaps? There are several plugin libraries and frameworks already. DI containers also offer similar features, when they don't eliminate the need entirely

Comment: It is not a plugin system as such, but yes I am manually referencing the dll file.

Comment: You *don't* need reflection for this BTW. If you are using ASP.NET MVC (Core or not), you probably use dependency injection already. Add configuratin code in your DLL to configure your DI container with the DLL's classes, services.

Comment: Can you point me to some documentation on how to do this Panagiotis?

Comment: @Neil some DI containers can register services dynamically. Or you could put your configuration code in a class with a well known name and look for it with Reflection in all loaded assemblies. Or you could have all configuration classes implement a well known interface and call everything that implements it with reflection

Comment: @Neil you mentioned MVC in your question. All MVC tutorials in the last couple of years show how to use dependency injection. You still haven't explaine *why* you want to do all that though. Why not just add a reference?

Comment: @Neil for example [this tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/older-versions/hands-on-labs/aspnet-mvc-4-dependency-injection) shows how to use the Unity DI container in ASP.NET MVC 4.

Comment: @Neil The [DI container used by .NET Core](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection/) is a .NET Standard 2.0 library so it can also be used by Full framework applications too. You can configure it manually or use the [HostBuilder](https://www.stevejgordon.co.uk/using-generic-host-in-dotnet-core-console-based-microservices) helper, also available as [a Standard 2.0 package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting/2.1.0-rc1-final). [This MSDN Magazine article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/mt707534.aspx) explains how it works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### No you can't really

Instantiating an object is a run-time concept. Declaration of a variable is a compile-time concept. You can instantiate an object that you load at run time, but you cannot declare one in your code, because it isn't known to the compiler at compile time.

That being said, you can still declare some variables that can hold a reference to your manually-loaded object instance. The obvious one is `object`. In your case you could also declare an `IEnumerable<object>` which should work due to covariance. Other than that, there is no type that is known to the compiler that you can write in your code.

If you have an `IEnumerable<object>` you can't do much more than iterate through it. You won't be able to access any of ExampleClass' properties or methods the normal way. You'd have to use reflection.

### An alternative

A common way to deal with this situation is to

1. Create a third assembly, containing only an interface, e.g. `IExampleClass`.
2. The assembly that implements `ExampleClass` has a reference to this third assembly.
3. ExampleClass is declared as `class ExampleClass : IExampleClass`
4. The console application also has a reference to this third assembly.
5. In the code for the console application, you can now declare a reference to you objects with a type specifier of `IExampleClass`, and access all the properties and methods that way.

So... your choices are reflection or an interface.

Answer (score 0):

```
Right click project -> Add -> Reference
```

If its a project in your solution, choose project, or press browse and choose your DLL.

You will find the namespace and class turn up in intellisense, and you can reference them normally with the correct types

Or if you really want just, use dynamic. alternatively you will have to reflect all the way unfortunately. This is your mission if you choose to accept it

The problem is, is you cant cast to `Type` at runtime, and have it any use at compile time.

**Update**

> The reason I want to do this is because if I reference the dll and
>   then run the console app through Visual Studio it works fine, but if I
>   run the exe of the console app, it throws an unhandled exception:
>   Could not load file or assembly 'EngineeringAssistantMVC', so i
>   figured loading the dll manually would work.

Make sure your bitness is right, also make sure you have referenced `EngineeringAssistantMVC.dll` as well and any other dll it relies on..

Comment: I am loading the DLL manually and not through the references.

Comment: @Neill *why*? What is the actual problem you want to solve? If you know the full type name at compile time, why not just add the reference?

Comment: The reason I want to do this is because if I reference the dll and then run the console app through Visual Studio it works fine, but if I run the exe of the console app, it throws an unhandled exception: Could not load file or assembly 'EngineeringAssistantMVC', so i figured loading the dll manually would work.